# CSS Page renders at different sizes in different browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, phpbb3

Bit of a weird one today. (Or maybe it's a perfectly normal one and I'm just tired)

I'm having an issue where my page renders at different sizes in different browsers. (as the title suggests)

The most obvious place that this can be seen is with my main content div, which is 1300px wide:

```
.cogs {
    width: 1300px;
}

#wrap {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

This DIV renders correctly with a width of 1300px in Chrome and Safari, but it has a width of about 1625px in both IE and Firefox, even though their developer tools will happily report that it's 1300px wide.

I'm guessing I must have triggered some sort of page zoom level, but I'm not sure exactly how I've managed this. I'm working with an existing theme for phpBB that I've just modified, and I'm not sure at what point this issue was introduced. I pressed Ctrl+0 before taking all of these screenshots, so it's not just browser zoom.

A picture paints a thousand words, so here's a screenshot of the page:

http://i.imgur.com/iLFSRoG.png

And here's a screenshot of the page with dev tools open. (I don't believe Safari has any dev tools built in)

http://i.imgur.com/e4urC4w.png

It's difficult for me to provide code samples, as I have no idea what part of the code the problem is in. There's quite a lot of code here. If you have something specific for me to look for, please tell me and I'll edit this question with the code. I realise this is a less than optimal way to organise the question, but I can't think of an easier way.

I also know it's frowned upon to provide a link without mirroring the code, but here is the live site: http://forums.industrialgaming.net.au/

Sorry for the horribly disorganized question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The linked pages looks exactly the same in Chrome 34, Fx 30 and Opera 12. Press `Ctrl + 0` :)

Comment: I've already pressed Ctrl + 0. I can make the pages look the same in Firefox and IE by zooming out a little bit, but at default zoom they look like the screenshot.

Comment: Crap, it's occurring on every webpage. Must be a browser setting somewhere...

Comment: Problem solved for IE10: Pressing Ctrl+0 sets zoom level to 125% instead of 100%. Good job, Microsoft, thanks for that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, yep, I'm definitely too tired. It was a Windows issue instead of a CSS issue:

[image: Windows Font Size]

Apparently this setting only takes effect in FF and IE, Chrome and Safari both ignore it.

Comment: yay for micros**t! :D